# Is there a simple tool to convert mysql to postgresql syntax?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I've tried the tools listed [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL), some with more success than others, but none gave me valid postgres syntax I could use (tinyint errors etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an official tool for porting a MySQL database to PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371991/is-there-an-official-tool-for-porting-a-mysql-database-to-postgresql)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a `mysqldump` option which makes it output PostgreSQL code:

```
mysqldump --compatible=postgresql ...
```

But that doesn't work too well.

Instead, please see the [mysql-to-postgres](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres) tool as [described in Linus Oleander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15670452/19163).

Comment: The documentation says that the output is just "more compatible". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible

Comment: Like @m_gol says, it doesn't work. It generates a sql file, but it can't be imported into pg.

Comment: @djjeck not only is it only "more compatible", but also it has nothing to do with postgres... as per the doc you point to: *"The only permitted value for this option is ansi"*.  So the text above should be `mysqldump --compatible=ansil`

Answer (score 18):

Try this one , it works like charm !!

```
http://www.sqlines.com/online
```

Comment: Um. Zero effect. It didn't change anything in the sql query at all, and the query had a "left(" in it. That should have been converted to a "substring(".

Comment: This tool is useless with many errors.

Comment: This tool is not useless, but it does have errors, so if you decide to use it, make sure to doublecheck the output. 
P.S. I was using it to translate from MySQL into PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5):

Install [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader) on Debian or Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install pgloader
```

Login as the postgres user and create a database

```
sudo su postgres
createdb -O user db_migrated
```

Transfer data from the mysql database to postgresql

```
pgloader mysql://user@localhost/db postgresql:///db_migrated
```

Check also [Dimitri Fontaine's rewrite of pgloader from python to common lisp](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2014/05/why-is-pgloader-so-much-faster/) so that he could implement real threading.

## Installation on other platforms

- [To install pgloader on Windows](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/issues/1017#issuecomment-566469443), you can use the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
- [To install pgloader on Mac](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader#building-from-sources-on-macos), you can use: `brew install --HEAD pgloader`.

Answer (score 4):

After some time on Google I found [this post](http://ruby.zigzo.com/2011/12/03/migrating-data-from-mysql-to-postgresql/).

1. Install the [mysql2psql](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres) gem using `[sudo] gem install mysql2psql`.
2. Create a config file by running `mysql2psql`. You'll see an error but a `mysql2psql.yml` file should have been created.
3. Edit `mysql2psql.yml`
4. Run `mysql2psql` again to migrate you data.

Tip: Set `force_truncate` to `true` in your `mysql2psql.yml` config file if you want the postgresql database to be cleared before migrating your data.

Comment: I used this and it worked well for me. "mysqldump --compatible=postgresql" (from vog's answer) has too many issues to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [py-mysql2pgsql](https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql). After installation it needs only simple configuration file in yml format (source, destination), e.g.:

```
# if a socket is specified we will use that
# if tcp is chosen you can use compression
mysql:
 hostname: localhost
 port: 3306
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
 username: mysql2psql
 password:
 database: mysql2psql_test
 compress: false
destination:
 # if file is given, output goes to file, else postgres
 file:
 postgres:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: mysql2psql
  password:
  database: mysql2psql_test
```

Usage:

```
> py-mysql2pgsql -h
usage: py-mysql2pgsql [-h] [-v] [-f FILE]

Tool for migrating/converting data from mysql to postgresql.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Show progress of data migration.
  -f FILE, --file FILE  Location of configuration file (default:
                        mysql2pgsql.yml). If none exists at that path,
                        one will be created for you.
```

More on its home page https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, I've found that [NMIG](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/NMIG) is nice up-to-date tool that directly converts from live mysql to postgres databases. It works better than `pgloader` for me, which cannot connect to mysql 8 by default.

**Usage**: see [readme](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/NMIG), or:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/AnatolyUss/NMIG nmig
cd nmig
npm ci
npm run build
# Now edit config/config.json
npm run start
```

Comment: Just used nmig on Windows and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PG Foundry](http://pgfoundry.org/), extra utilities for Postgres tend to live there. I believe that the tool you're looking for does exist though.

Comment: There are some projects there, but I couldn't find one that works

Answer (score 0):

There is one piece of pay software listed on this postgresql page:
http://www.postgresql.org/download/products/1

and this is on pgFoundry:
http://pgfoundry.org/projects/mysql2pgsql/

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Converting_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL) lists the syntax differences, but a simple working query converter i haven't found yet. Using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) package instead of raw SQL could prevent these issues.

I'm currently hacking up a converter for a legacy codebase:

```
function mysql2pgsql($mysql){
    return preg_replace("/limit (\d+), *(\d+)/i", "limit $1 offset $2", preg_replace("/as '([^']+)'/i", 'as "$1"', $mysql)); // Note: limit needs order
}
```

For `CREATE` statements, [SQLines](http://www.sqlines.com/online) converts most of them online. I still had to edit the mysqldump afterwards, though:

```
"mediumtext" -> "text", "^LOCK.*" -> "", "^UNLOCK.*" -> "", "`" -> '"', "'" -> "''" in 'data', "0000-00-00" -> "2000-01-01", deduplicate constraint names, " CHARACTER SET utf8 " -> " ".
"int(10)" -> "int" was missed in the last table, so pass that part of the mysqldump through http://www.sqlines.com/online again.
```

Answer (score -3):

you will most likely never get a tool for such task which would do all of your job for you. be prepared to do some refactoring work yourself.

Comment: The need to refactor is also my experience with other conversion tools, because of the many incompatible [SQL dialects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_relational_database_management_systems). However [pgloader](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader) (mentioned in another answer below) worked surprisingly well for databases of several million lines.